# PHP: Update filename with current timestamp

Tags: php

I would like to update the existing filename with the current date (and time, if possible). To achieve this I wrote following code:

```
function updateName() {
        if (file_exists('files/test.sql')) {
                $oldName='files/test.sql';
                $newName='test_'.date('d-m-Y').'.sql';
                rename ($oldName,$newName);
        }
}
```

But, this throws an error as

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  rename(files/test.sql,test_12-02-2016.sql): No such file or directory in /updateFileName.php on line 7"
```

I can confirm that the file exists in the files directory.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: if you want to rename the existing file then replace $newName like this:

$newName='files/yesy_'.date('d-m-Y').'.sql';

Comment: @MahaDev, didn't make any difference.. Now the error message is "PHP message: PHP Warning:  rename(files/test.sql,files/test_12-02-2016.sql)....

Comment: @Ravi, i checked your code on my local system and there is no issue with this.

Comment: @VikashKumar: Thanks mate.. not sure whats wrong and why this script is still failing.. This piece of code is stopping me to finish my project..

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP looks for the file at the directory where the script is running from. Either move your file there or specify the location of your file.

Comment: Hi Corona.. Thanks for the reply. The PHP file and files directory are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateName() {    
if (file_exists('./files/test.sql')) {

            $oldName='files/test.sql';
            $newName='files/test_'.date('d-m-Y').'.sql';
            rename ($oldName,$newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate... but still no joy.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. The code was correct, but the issue was because of spelling mistake in my file name.